# Wie übersetzt man "User Experience" im Zusammenhang mit Anwendungsprogrammen (Software) richtig?

Tags: translation

Man findet für gewöhnlich zwei Übersetzungen:

1. Nutzererfahrung
2. Nutzererlebnis

Die erste Variante erscheint mir vor allem missverständlich. Der Anwender macht ja keine Erfahrungen. Ihm wird eine Software zur Verwendung angeboten, die sich auf eine bestimmte Art- und Weise benutzen lässt.

Die zweite Variante ist mir zu übertrieben. Software ist ein Arbeitsmittel - Erlebnisse hat man vielleicht im Urlaub - aber eher selten im Büro.

Also: welcher Begriff trifft das gemeinte im Deutschen am besten?

Comment: Einfach "UX" benutzen und hoffen daß niemand nachfragt ;)

Comment: Tja, im Deutschen tut man sich mit dem Begriff `Erfahrung` und den anhaftenden Konnotationen immer schwer.

Comment: @Michael: es gibt 8 Diskussionen auf leo.org dazu!: http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=user%20experience&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on  da ist bestimmt etwas schönes dabei für dich

Comment: @falkb vielen Dank für den Hinweis: am besten gefällt mir "wahrnehmen"

Comment: Bevor ich es wieder vergesse, möchte ich hier noch das Wort *Zugänglichkeit* in den Raum schmeißen, das zumindest einige Aspekte m. E. recht gut trifft.

Answer (score 13):

`User experience` ist ein sehr neuer Begriff, der in den letzten 2–3 Jahren in den englischsprachigen zu einem Buzzword wurde, aber auch vor dem Hype nicht lange existierte. Die Leute, die in dem Bereich arbeiteten, identifizierten sich vorher meistens mit dem Begriff `usability`, nicht `user experience` (aber auch andere Gebiete wie Requirements Engineering werden heute häufig von den UX Spezialisten abgedeckt). Die "User Experience Professional's association" bekam diesen Namen in 2012 – [vorher hieß sie "Usability Professionals' Association"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability_Professionals%27_Association). Und wenn man ein Fachbuch wie "Measuring the user experience" von Tullis und Albert aufmacht, stellt man schnell fest, dass auf dem Deckblatt zwar "User experience" steht, aber ziemlich alle Kapitelüberschriften von "usability metrics" reden, nicht "user experience metrics".

[image]

Ich kenne keine Statistiken darüber, aber ich arbeite an einem Lehrstuhl für Software Engineering in einer deutschen Universität und lese auch immer wieder Vertreter der deutschen IT Presse. Daher denke ich, dass ich einen guten Überblick habe.

In meiner Erfahrung benutzt niemand eine Übersetzung für `User experience`. In einem formalen oder akademischen Kontext reden alle immer noch von `Benutzbarkeit`, was die Übersetzung von `Usability` ist. Das ist das Wort, was in den Lehrbüchern steht, und was die Professoren von Studenten verlangen, wenn sie sich gegen "Denglisch" in Abschlussarbeiten auflehnen. In großen Industrieunternehmen kommen solche Trends sowieso sehr spät an, und ich denke, dass der Begriff noch gar nicht von der Presse aufgegriffen worden ist, die sich an Managern aus der Art von Unternehmen richtet, e.g. Computerworld (aber Vorsicht hier, ich lese Computerworld eher selten).

Es gibt sicher auch die Menschen, die sehr vom US-Trend beeinflusst sind, und denen eine Unterscheidung zwischen User experience und Usability wichtig ist, oder auch nur modern sein möchten und sich vom verstaubten Image der Usability differenzieren. Das sind aber häufig die Menschen, die zu viel Formalität verabscheuen und nicht auf einen sauberen Sprachgebrauch achten. Sie benutzen meistens den englischen Begriff `User experience`, der einem deutschen Professor erst mal den Magen umdreht, aber die hippen, trendigen early adopters gar nicht stört.

Daher sieht die Wirklichkeit so aus, dass es noch gar keinen etablierten Begriff gibt. Im Moment hast Du drei Optionen:

- benutze weiterhin `Benutzbarkeit`. Dann werden dich die meisten Deutschen aus der IT-Branche perfekt verstehen (außer du möchtest die neuesten Erkenntnisse auf dem Gebiet betonen und vertrittst die Ansicht, dass die nicht zur alten `usability` gehören, sondern erst durch das neue `user experience` hereingebracht werden.)
- benutze 'User experience' ohne Übersetzung. Alle, die die US-amerikanische Presse auf dem Gebiet verfolgen, werden dich gut verstehen. Viele andere, auch Leute, die sich damit ihr Leben lang beschäftigen, werden erstmal nicht wissen, was alles dahinter steckt, und du wirst es wohl auch erklären müssen.
- benutze irgendeine wörtliche Übersetzung. Beide von Dir vorgeschlagenen Begriffe könnten benutzt werden. "Benutzererfahrung" ist mehr wörtlich, "Benutzererlebnis" wird mehr der Idee gerecht, dass wir alle Aspekte der Interaktion des Benutzers mit unserem Produkt beeinflussen möchten, auch die emotionalen Aspekte. Keins ist ein Wort, was bisher benutzt wird, und du wirst ziemlich jedem erklären müssen, was du damit meinst. Von der eigentlichen Wortbedeutung her werden viele verstehen, welchen Vorgang du meinst, aber wenn du über das ganze Feld redest, wird keiner von allein darauf kommen, dass du dasselbe wie (oder eine Übermenge von) dem meinst, was sie schon als `Benutzbarkeit` kennen. Ich würde aber immer die Form mit "Be-" vorziehen, weil ich `Benutzer` und `Benutzbarkeit` viel häufiger treffe als `Nutzer` und `Nutzbarkeit` (eigentlich existiert das zweite Wort soweit ich weiß gar nicht).

Ich erwarte, dass sich das irgendwann ändert. Der Trend wird bestimmt auch hier ankommen, sowie viele frühere IT Trends angekommen sind. Welches Wort sich durchsetzt, kann nicht vorhergesagt werden, alle drei von mir aufgezählten Alternativen sind denkbar. (Wie du von meinem Post merkst, benutzen selbst die anti-denglisch Professoren den Begriff Software Engineering und nicht Softwaretechnik, so dass es durchaus denkbar ist, dass der englische Begriff die Oberhand gewinnt). Bis dann werden aber bestimmt einige Jahre vergehen.

Comment: " vom verstaubten Image der Usability differenzieren" - sehe ich nicht so. UX und Usability sind nicht gleich zu setzen, sondern haben andere Aspekte.

Comment: @FrankL Ich habe unterschiedlichste Ansichten zum Thema gesehen, aber das ist nicht der Ort, sie auszudiskutieren. Es gibt Leute, die es so sehen, und darin einen Grund finden, nicht den Begriff "Benutzbarkeit" zu benutzen. Wenn der OP (oder seine Kommunikationspartner) nicht dazu zaehlen, dann hat er eine Moeglichkeit mehr. Aber diese moegliche Assotiationen sollten ihm bewusst sein, wenn er entscheidet, welchen Begriff er nutzen wird.

Comment: Der Begriff klingt wieder irgendwie nach Scheinwissenschaft, und indem man ihn nicht übersetzt, klingt er schön hochtrabend. Man beachte, dass er für jemanden aus dem englischsprachigen Sprachraum auch nur simpel "Benutzererfahrung" heißt. Im Grunde genommen geht es doch nur um den Benutzerblickwinkel hinsichtlich einer Produktanalyse (siehe z.B. http://www.designwissen.net/seiten/produktanalyse-nach-funktionen-und-kosten ), aber +1 für deine recht objektive Analyse.

Comment: @rumtscho Ja stimmt eigentlich.

Comment: Und was ist jetzt der Unterschied zwischen "user experience" und "usability"? Nur dass der eine Begriff älter und für das Marketing daher abgenutzt ist? Was sollen überhaupt "angestaubte Begriffe" sein? "Mensch" ist auch ein angestaubter Begriff. Und wie kann man sich mit "User experience" identifizieren? Erzähl das bloß keinem Psychologen! :)

Comment: `UX` (/ju:'ɛks/) hat sich wegen dem schönen Akronym behauptet, sonst würde es gar nicht _user experience_ heißen.

Answer (score 5):

Ich habe *Nutzererlebnis* und *Anwendererlebnis* schon öfter [gelesen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Experience) und gehört. In dem Zusammenhang wird das Wort *Benutzerfreundlichkeit* auch oft genutzt, allerdings erfasst es nur einen Teilaspekt des Anwendererlebnisses.

Comment: Ich finde Benutzerfreundlichkeit am passendsten, auch wenn die beiden Worte mit "-erlebnis" sicher direkter übersetzt wären. +1

Answer (score 3):

Das hängt vielleicht von der Art der Software ab. "gute Bedienbarkeit" "gute Benutzbarkeit" könnten funktionieren.

Vielleicht kannst Du den Satz, in dem "user experience" vorkommt, auch umformulieren: "great user experience" -> "so einfach und intuitiv zu benutzen, dass es fast schon keine Arbeit, sondern Vergnügen ist".

Comment: Benutzung und Bedienung als Grundlage für eine Übersetzung machen mehr Sinn wenn man es kurz fassen will. Wobei das "gut" ja nicht verpflichtend wäre. +1

Comment: Das Problem entsteht, wenn man sich die widerstrebenden Ziele des Marketings zu eigen macht, ohne sie zu verstehen. Eine intuitiv benutzbare Software wird ja gar nicht wahrgenommen und ist daher das Gegenteil von einem Erlebnis. Die tägliche Autofahrt zur Arbeit geschieht auch so reibungslos, dass man sich daran eben nicht erinnert. Oder das Essen mit Messer und Gabel, nachdem man es gelernt hat. Aber das Marketing versucht es zu einem Erlebnis aufzublasen wie den Kampf gegen den Tiger im Dschungel.

Answer (score 3):

Beides ist richtig. Wobei einige Aspekte für die Nutzererfahrung sprechen:

Unter User Experience wird (laut ISO Definition) das Erlebnis vor, während und nach einer Softwarenutzung verstanden. Das "während" ist der Teil, wo die Usability (auf deutsch Gebrauchstauglichkeit) wichtig ist. Das "vor" und "danach" sind psychologische Effekte wie Voreinstellung, Vorwissen, Vorerfahrung der Materie etc. Nach der Benutzung hat man Erfahrungen gesammelt und vergleicht diese mit den Erwartungen, die man vorher hatte. User Experience setzt also die zeitlose Gebrauchstauglichkeit in einen zeitlichen Erfahrungshorizont. Daher wäre die Nutzererfahrung wohl treffender, weil das N.erlebnis m.E. eine punktuelle Erfahrung ist.

Ich persönlich spreche aber lieber von Software oder Produkt Erlebnis ;-)

Erschwerend kommt noch eine Doppelbedeutung von UX hinzu. UX wird neuerdings auch als Disziplin zwischen Design, IT und Marketing gesehen. Hierbei ist die Gestaltung einer positiven Produkt/Softwareerfahrung das Augenmerk. Dort wird sich aus einem Potpouri aus Psychologie, Gamification, Marketing, Grafik, Text, Design, Usability, Conversionoptimierung und Vermarktungsmethoden bedient, um neben begeisterten Nutzern auch klingelnde Kassen zu haben.

Das mag jetzt klugscheissernd sein, aber noch ein paar Worte zu Usability - auf deutsch Gebrauchstauglichkeit. Nutzerfreundlichkeit greift hier zur kurz, denn eine gute Usability zeichnet aus, dass ein bestimmtes Ziel (effektiv) in kurzer Zeit und ohne Umwege (effizient) und zur Zufriedenheit (Nutzerfreundlichkeit) der Nutzer erreicht wird. Ich möchte mein Ziel direkt und schnell erreichen und nicht nur freundlich oder benutzbar ;-) Daher spricht man von Tauglichkeit für den Gebrauch oder in ISO-deutsch  Gebrauchstauglichkeit.

Ich persönlich finde Usability runder im Sprechen. Teste unsere Dienstleister aber mit Gebr. um ihren Kenntnisstand zu checken. Mein kleiner Buzzword-Check.

Comment: Letzter Absatz: "Mit Gebr." - mit Gebrüder?

Comment: @user unknown Genau. Wenn die dann Gebrüder sagen, dann weiß ich die kennen das nicht ;-)

Comment: _Produkterlebnis_ bzw. sogar **_Produktgenuss_** sind inzwischen auch meine Favoriten. Die wörtliche Übersetzung liefert einfach keine guten Ergebnisse (und geschlechtsneutral ist _Produkt_ auch noch). Analog wäre die _Customer Experience_ aus dem Marketingjargon der BWL dann ein _Warengenuss_ oder _Dienstleistungsgenuss_. Alternativ könnte man bspw. auch _Nutzfreude_ bilden.

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Experience) nennt außer der Benutzung des englischen Begriffes oder der direkten Übersetzung „Nutzererfahrung“ die Möglichkeiten „Nutzererlebnis“,  „Nutzungserlebnis“ und „Anwendererlebnis“.

Answer (score 1):

*User Experience* ist einer jener Termini, die in der Praxis sehr selten ins Deutsche übersetzt werden.

> Die User Experience wurde untersucht.

Die "richtigste" Übersetzung ist wohl *Nutzererlebnis*, ich würde das aber mit dem englischen Begriff kombinieren, z. B.

> Die User Experience (Nutzererlebnis) wurde untersucht.

oder

> Das Nutzererlebnis (User Experience) wurde untersucht.

Comment: ich finde J.H.Campe gut, der für über 10000 Fremdwörter deutsche Entsprechungen gefunden hat, von denen etwa 300 heute fester Bestandteil der Sprache sind. Daran sollte man sich heute oft ein Beispiel nehmen. Es ist sogar oft relativ leicht etwas zu finden.

Comment: Bin grundsätzlich bei dir, dass viel zu oft Anglizismen verwendet werden, obwohl es brauchbare deutsche Entsprechungen gibt. Im konkreten Fall finde ich das Original aber besser. Auch weil ich niemanden kenne, der das übersetzt (bin vom Fach).

Answer (score 1):

Wortgetreu ist *Erfahrung* natürlich die einzig richtige Übersetzung. Wikipedia merkt das auch an, empfiehlt aber zugleich *Erlebnis* als 'bessere' Variante.

> deutsch wörtlich: Nutzererfahrung, besser: Nutzererlebnis oder Nutzungserlebnis

Ich sehe das anders und stimme dir zu, dass man beim Umgang mit Software nichts *erlebt*, folglich kann ich kein *Erlebnis* gehabt haben.

Im Wiki-Artikel heißt es:

> User Experience [wird] über die Wahrnehmungen und Reaktionen einer Person, die sich bei der Benutzung oder der erwarteten Verwendung eines Produktes ergeben, definiert. Dazu gehören die Emotionen des Nutzers, die psychologischen und physiologischen Reaktionen, die Erwartungen und das Verhalten.

Ich kenne es zu gut, dass man Software installiert und sofort wieder runterschmeißt, weil sie absolut unhandlich ist. Und andere Programme überzeugen einen sofort. In meiner täglichen Arbeit muss ich Produkte verwenden, die ich hasse; und darf jene nicht installieren, die ich gerne hätte.
Dabei kommen jede Menge an 'Wahrnehmungen' und 'Reaktion' zusammen; ich kann aber immer noch nicht behaupten, jemals ein *Erlebnis* gehabt zu haben.

Dafür mache ich aber Erfahrungen. Ich sammle Wissen, ich finde heraus, wie was funktioniert, wie ich etwas schneller lösen kann, wie ich Fehler umgehen kann etc.
Jedoch wird genau dies **nicht** unter 'User Experience' definiert. Es geht nicht um mein Wissen, sondern um *perceptions* und *reactions*.

Nüchtern betrachtet ist es ziemlich schwer einen passenden Begriff zu finden; und ich würde fast so weit gehen und sagen, dass der englische Begriff schon unglücklich gewählt ist.

Als Fazit kann ich aber nur sagen, dass es keinen wirklich treffenden Begriff gibt, der das ganze beschreiben kann. Und daher würde ich 'User Experience' wortgetreu übersetzen. Und das ist 'Nutzererfahrung' – auch wenn dieser in der Tat zweideutig ist (und genau das ist vermutlich der Grund, warum man im Deutschen auf *Erlebnis* ausweicht – im Englischen gibt es wohlbemerkt keinen weiteren Begriff).

Answer (score 1):

Letztlich wird sich rausstellen müssen, was sich im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch einschleift. Wie Du richtig feststellst, scheinen sich bisher *Nutzererfahrung* und *Nutzererlebnis* durchzusetzen.

Zur Richtigkeit/Unrichtigkeit vielleicht aber noch ein anderer Gedankengang:

*Erfahrung* ist in diesem Kontext nicht so unrichtig, wie von den meisten hier angenommen. Zwar spricht auch der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Erfahrung) bei Erfahrung immer nur davon, dass man dadurch klüger wird und Kenntnisse sammelt, aber es gibt ja auch z.B. die *Nahtoderfahrung*, die es im Englischen als *near death experience* gibt. (Der Duden erklärt das recht geschraubt und ziemlich amüsant als "Erfahrung reanimierter Personen, die bereits klinisch tot waren, mit dem Sterben, mit dem Tod". Ich finde, hier geht es eindeutig um ein *Erlebnis*, nicht darum, dass man Erfahrung in/mit etwas hätte.)
Ähnlich verhält es sich m.E. bei "ich habe die Erfahrung gemacht, dass dieses Programm Mist ist". Hier ist die Grenze zwar etwas verschwommener, aber dennoch finde ich, dass *experience* gut mit *Erfahrung* wiederzugeben ist. (Ganz zu schweigen von esoterischen Kontexten, wo etwas "ganz bewusst erfahren" wird.)

*Erlebnis*. Natürlich ist ein Erlebnis meistens ein "von jemandem als in einer bestimmten Weise beeindruckend erlebtes Geschehen" <sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Erlebnis)</sup>, es im Sinne von "etwas erlebtes" zu verwenden finde ich aber jetzt nicht so wahnsinnig schrecklich.

Egal, wofür sich der Sprachgebrauch letztlich entscheidet, es ist davon auszugehen, dass das jeweilige Wort eine Bedeutungserweiterung erfahren/erleben wird.

Fazit: Mein Favorit ist Nutzererfahrung, lasse mich aber auch vom Nutzererlebnis überzeugen.

Answer (score 1):

Richtig? Bedienbarkeit. Die Bedienung ist einfach. Es ist einfach zu bedienen. Die Nutzerführung ist gut gestaltet und resultiert in einer einfachen Bedienbarkeit.

Der Bediener der Software profitiert von einer einfachen Bedienbarkeit.

User Experience focusses a lot on the experience part. Aka. the Software being a show that needs to be pleasant on the senses.

In Germany we focus more on that things actually work. It's supposed to be less flashy and more functional. So a direct translation is not possible since the context and culture are different.

An operator operates a software and that makes easy operability a prime concern.